# Converting a large dataset into 2D Array and then into 2D Multiples based in condtion to Total Columns

Tags: arrays, vba

By no means, I am an experienced coder, but do need assistance with the following task.

I have a medium size to a large dataset that grows by rows with a fixed no. columns (81), for later distribution (no pivot tbl and/or formulas).

The below is the code that has so far able to achieve:
Declare all arrays by month populated from the dataset, create 1D array to add all columns and later paste transposed into the MONTH wksht.

and stuck on pasting past JAN

Thanks in advance

```
 Sub RangeSize2()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim ws1 As Worksheet
 Dim ws3 As Worksheet

 Dim FinalSelection As Range, LRs3, LCs3 As Long, X As Integer
 Dim Rx1, Rx2, Rx3, Rx4, Rx5, Rx6, Rx7, Rx8, Rx9, Rx10, Rx11, Rx12, Ry1, Ry2,     Ry3, Ry4, Ry5, Ry6, Ry7, Ry8, Ry9, Ry10, Ry11, Ry12 As Long

Dim monthnames() As Variant
monthnames = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")


Dim arrJAN(), arrFEB(), arrMAR() As Variant
Dim RG01, RG02, RG03, RG04, RG05, RG06, RG07, RG08, RG09, RG10, RG11, RG12 As  Range
Dim c As Range, v As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MONTH")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

LRs3 = Sheets("DATA").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LCs3 = Sheets("DATA").Cells(3, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(4, 1).Select
Sheets("DATA").Select

For X = 1 To 12

    For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:B"))
        If c.Value = monthnames(X) Then
       v = c.Value '= v
            If FinalSelection Is Nothing Then
                Set FinalSelection = Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, LCs3))
            Else
                Set FinalSelection = Union(FinalSelection,  Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, LCs3)))
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    ''msgBox v

    If Not FinalSelection Is Nothing Then FinalSelection.Select


            If X = 1 Then
                 Ry1 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                 Rx1 = FinalSelection.Row
                 'msgBox v & " - " & Rx1 & " - " & Ry1
            End If

            If X = 2 Then
                 Ry2 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                 Rx2 = Ry1 + 1
                 'msgBox v & " - " & Rx2 & " - " & Ry2
             End If

             If X = 3 Then
                Ry3 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx3 = Ry2 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx3 & " - " & Ry3
            End If

             If X = 4 Then
                Ry4 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx4 = Ry3 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx4 & " - " & Ry4
            End If

             If X = 5 Then
                Ry5 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx5 = Ry4 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx5 & " - " & Ry5
            End If

             If X = 6 Then
                Ry6 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx6 = Ry5 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx6 & " - " & Ry6
            End If

             If X = 7 Then
                Ry7 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx7 = Ry6 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx7 & " - " & Ry7
            End If

             If X = 8 Then
                Ry8 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx8 = Ry7 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx8 & " - " & Ry8
            End If

             If X = 9 Then
                Ry9 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx9 = Ry8 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx9 & " - " & Ry9
            End If

             If X = 10 Then
                Ry10 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx10 = Ry9 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx10 & " - " & Ry10
            End If

             If X = 11 Then
                Ry11 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx11 = Ry10 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx11 & " - " & Ry11
            End If

             If X = 12 Then

                Ry12 = FinalSelection.Rows.count + FinalSelection.Row - 1
                Rx12 = Ry11 + 1
                'msgBox v & " - " & Rx12 & " - " & Ry12
            End If

  Next X

 'RG01, RG02, RG03, RG04, RG05, RG06, RG07, RG08, RG09, RG10, RG11, RG12

 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''looping & pasting each range

Dim RR As Long, CC As Long
Dim TotalCol As Double

'JAN''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

 ws3.Activate
    RG01 = ws3.Range(Cells(Rx1, 1), Cells(Ry1, LCs3)).Value2
    arrJAN = RG01
    Dim JANTotal() As Variant
    ReDim JANTotal(1 To LCs3)

    TotalCol = 0

    For CC = 1 To LCs3
            For RR = 1 To UBound(arrJAN, 1)
            On Error Resume Next
                TotalCol = TotalCol + arrJAN(RR, CC)
                JANTotal(CC) = TotalCol
            Next RR
     TotalCol = 0
    Next CC

ws1.Activate
    'paste to MONT SHt
    ws1.Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(LCs3 + 3, 3)) = Application.Transpose(JANTotal)
 '   Erase arrJAN
  '  Erase JANTotal
RR = 0
CC = 0
 'FEB''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 ws3.Activate
 RG02 = ws3.Range(Cells(Rx2, 1), Cells(Ry2, LCs3)).Value2
       RG02 = arrFEB
    Dim FEBTotal() As Variant
    ReDim FEBTotal(1 To LCs3)

    TotalCol = 0

    For CC = 1 To LCs3
            For RR = 1 To UBound(arrFEB, 1)
            On Error Resume Next
                TotalCol = TotalCol + arrFEB(RR, CC)
                FEBTotal(CC) = TotalCol
            Next RR
     TotalCol = 0
    Next CC
ws1.Activate
    'paste to MONT SHt
    ws1.Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(LCs3 + 3, 4)) = Application.Transpose(FEBTotal)
 '   Erase arrFEB

Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Comment: What programming language is this? I'm also not sure what you expect from this code and what your problem is.

Comment: I am using VBA - and my aim is to break down the large data into a report that adds the column based on column B values (months)

Comment: Please add the VBA tag to the question then.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple issues in the code. One is obviously `RG02 = arrFEB`, think it would be `arrFEB=RG02`. But why go for such an overkill. Why not use something simple as below

```
Option Base 1
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Dim Rng, smRng, CrtRng As Range, LRs3, LCs3, Cl As Long, M As Integer, V As String, Sm As Double
Dim monthnames() As Variant
monthnames = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MONTH")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

LRs3 = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LCs3 = ws3.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set Rng = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(1, 1), ws3.Cells(LRs3, LCs3))
Set CrtRng = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(1, 2), ws3.Cells(LRs3, 2))
'MsgBox Rng.Address

For M = 1 To 12
V = monthnames(M)
    For Cl = 1 To LCs3
    Set smRng = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(1, Cl), ws3.Cells(LRs3, Cl))
        If Cl <> 2 Then
        Sm = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(CrtRng, V, smRng)
        'ws3.Cells(LRs3 + 2 + M, Cl).Value = Sm   ' for checking below data range by applying data filter
        ws1.Cells(3 + Cl, 2 + M).Value = Sm
        Else
        'ws3.Cells(LRs3 + 2 + M, Cl).Value = V   ' for checking below data range by applying data filter
        ws1.Cells(3 + Cl, 2 + M).Value = V
        End If
    Next Cl
Next M

End Sub
```

Hope it will be useful.